# jquery not working in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried using jQuery on my website, but it did not seem to work. this code doesn't work. When I click on #test, it doesn't hide. Please help. Thanks!

this is my Html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p id="#test">Hello world !</p>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my code.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $('#test').hide();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: remove the `#` from `<p id="#test">`

Answer (score 5):

your html is wrong, remove hash `#` sign:

```
<p id="test">Hello world !</p> // this is right
```

while you have written:

```
<p id="#test">Hello world !</p> // this is wrong
```

**NOTE:**

you can get current element reference using `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }); 
});
```

`$("#test")` means that select element which has **id** equal to **test**

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the meta character with `\\`,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#\\#test').click(function() {
        $('#\\#test').hide();
    }); 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/df9kfta6/)